# "Last but not Least" or "The last but not the least"?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

Is it because, in most cases, we use "**last but not least**" after mentioning some items that don't add "**The**" to the phrase? or is it just an **accepted exception**? Shouldn't the correct way be like " **the last but not the least**" or simply just "**the last but not least**"?

Comment: Think of "last but not least" as a comment on the list, not a part of it.

Comment: 'Last but not least' is a compound pragmatic marker, twinning ordering-within-the-article ('last') and emphasis/highlighting (the litotes 'not least').

Comment: Regarding your question "Is it because ..." - please explain what "it" refers to.

Comment: _Last but not least_ is a fixed phrase. You don't add things to fixed phrases.

Comment: As @Robusto says.   If it helps...  "I have an apple, a pear and - last (on my list) but not least - an orange."